# Speed up the launching of already compiled code in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

Whenever I try to launch a Java application with a default Run Application configuration, the Make process is started, regardless of whether there are any changes requiring compilation or not. With no changes the process still takes a few seconds on my computer.

I tried to overcome this problem by removing the `Make` position from the run configuration and checking the `Make project automatically` in the settings. Unfortunately, this solution spawned another problem: sometimes when I do introduce some changes and run the application, the automatic build is not yet finished and the old version of the program is launched instead.

In other words, I'd like to emulate the behaviour of the Eclipse run command:

- If there are no changes, run the app immediately (a fraction of second on my computer).
- If there are some changes, compile them and then run the app.

How can I do this in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IntelliJ Ultimate, then you can only vote http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128944

If you are using IntelliJ Community, then I have a workaround for you - https://www.reddit.com/r/IntelliJIDEA/comments/2g3by6/hacking_intellij_for_faster_compilation/